# How to include a stream into json'body with Delphi and REST components

Tags: json, delphi

i need to send a PDF file to YouSign (to sign document), using JSON and REST Components (RESTClient, RESTRequest)
My JSON must be like this :

```
{
    "name": "MonFichier.pdf",
    "content": "JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz9MNCjIzMCAwIG9iag08PC9MaW5lYXJpemVkIDEvTCAxMTI1MDAvTyAyMzIvRSA3NzUyMS9OIDIvVCAxMTIxMDcvSCBbIDEzNzEgNDg2XT4+DWVuZG9iag0gICAgICAgICAgICAgDQozMDQgMCBvYmoNPDwvRGVjb2RlUGFybXM8PC9Db2x1bW5zIDUvUHJlZGljdG9yIDEyPj4vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0lEWzxGRUQzRjY5MDY3OTA0OEM4RUE2RUFGQjgyQkZCNzM1Qz48QUUyNTY1RTRDOEUzN0Q0ODhEMkRBRDE2OUZGMjBCRTk"
}
```

I managed to read the PDF file, transform it into TStringstream BASE64 but I cannot include it in the JSON to put it in the body of the RESTRequest
How can we do ?
Thank you in advance for your ideas

Comment: Hey Marc, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you attach the code that you already have? This would help other people to give you a tailored answer.

Comment: Hello Nick
I found the solution
it was enough to create the TBase64Encoding
with (0):
with TBase64Encoding.Create (0) do

Thank you